# Prove or disprove absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove or Disprove:

if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} max\{a_n,\frac{1}{n^2}\}$ is also absolutely convergent.

Comment: are you sure? this is not correct for $a_n = n^{-3}$ for example

Comment: Sorry I missed a negative: $\max(a_n, n^{-2}) = \frac{1}{2} ( a_n+n^{-2} + |a_n-n^{-2}|).$

Comment: $ \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\max(a, b)+\min(a, b) = a+b\\\\ \max(a, b)-\min(a, b) = |a-b|\end{array}\right| \implies  \max(a, b) = \frac{1}{2} (a+b+|a-b|) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think I just missed something pretty simple:
The sum of two convergent series is also convergent.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} max\{a_n,\frac{1}{n^2}\} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{n^2}| $

therefore by the first comparison test, the original series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The maximum is no greater than the sum. (For positive numbers. Consider absolute values.)

Answer (score 1):

1) Consider $a_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \ \forall \ n$ and compare to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$

2) Consider $\frac{1}{n^2} \leq a_n \ \forall \ n$ and compare to $\sum_n a_n$